# Need help SQL Server INSERT IF NOT EXISTS statement

Tags: sql-server

I am basically trying to transform this sql statement to beable to run it multiple times a day without duplicating the results.  I did not write the code and I have tried some IF NOT EXISTS statements with no luck on getting the syntax correct.  Please let me know what needs to be done in order to insert the results only if they currently do not exist in the table already.
Thank you for your help.

```
INSERT INTO Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping
(ProductId, SpecificationAttributeOptionId, AllowFiltering, ShowOnProductPage,     DisplayOrder)

SELECT PD.Id  AS ProductId, 
   sao.Id AS SpecificationAttributeOptionId, 
   '1'    AS AllowFiltering, 
   '0'    AS ShowOnProductPage, 
   sao.DisplayOrder AS DisplayOrder
FROM Product as PD
join (
  select id, 
         name, 
         ymin as pcmin,       
         case when ymax < ymin then 99 else ymax end as pcmax,
         case when ymax < ymin then  0 else ymin end as ccmin,
         ymax as ccmax
  from (
        select id, 
               name, 
               convert(int, SUBSTRING(name, loc-2, 2)) as ymin,
               convert(int, SUBSTRING(name, loc+1, 2)) as ymax
        from (
              select id, 
                     name, 
                     loc
              from (
                    select id, 
                           name,
                           CHARINDEX('-', name) as loc
                    from PRODUCT
                    where CHARINDEX('-', name) > 0
                   ) as tbl
              where SUBSTRING(name, loc-3, 1) = ' ' 
                and SUBSTRING(name, loc+3, 1) = ' '
             ) as rng
       ) as yrs
 ) as PdRng
on PdRng.id = PD.id
join (
  select *
  from SpecificationAttributeOption 
  where isnumeric(Name) > 0
    and len(rtrim(Name)) = 4 AND SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttributeId = '7'
 ) as sao       
ON convert(int, Right(sao.Name, 2)) between PdRng.pcmin and PdRng.pcmax
OR convert(int, Right(sao.Name, 2)) between PdRng.ccmin and PdRng.ccmax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 
    PD.Id  AS ProductId, 
    sao.Id AS SpecificationAttributeOptionId, 
    '1'    AS AllowFiltering, 
    '0'    AS ShowOnProductPage, 
    sao.DisplayOrder AS DisplayOrder
  FROM Product as PD
  join (
    select id, 
           name, 
           ymin as pcmin,       
           case when ymax < ymin then 99 else ymax end as pcmax,
           case when ymax < ymin then  0 else ymin end as ccmin,
           ymax as ccmax
    from (
          select id, 
                 name, 
                 convert(int, SUBSTRING(name, loc-2, 2)) as ymin,
                 convert(int, SUBSTRING(name, loc+1, 2)) as ymax
          from (
                select id, 
                       name, 
                       loc
                from (
                      select id, 
                             name,
                             CHARINDEX('-', name) as loc
                      from PRODUCT
                      where CHARINDEX('-', name) > 0
                     ) as tbl
                where SUBSTRING(name, loc-3, 1) = ' ' 
                  and SUBSTRING(name, loc+3, 1) = ' '
               ) as rng
         ) as yrs
   ) as PdRng
  on PdRng.id = PD.id
  join (
    select *
    from SpecificationAttributeOption 
    where 
      isnumeric(Name) > 0
      and len(rtrim(Name)) = 4 
      AND SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttributeId = '7'
   ) as sao       
  ON convert(int, Right(sao.Name, 2)) between PdRng.pcmin and PdRng.pcmax
  OR convert(int, Right(sao.Name, 2)) between PdRng.ccmin and PdRng.ccmax
)
INSERT INTO Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping(
  ProductId, SpecificationAttributeOptionId, AllowFiltering, ShowOnProductPage, DisplayOrder
)
SELECT 
  ProductId, SpecificationAttributeOptionId, AllowFiltering, ShowOnProductPage, DisplayOrder
FROM T
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping M 
    WHERE
      T.ProductId = M.ProductId 
      AND T.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = M.SpecificationAttributeOptionId
      AND T.AllowFiltering = M.AllowFiltering
      AND T.ShowOnProductPage = M.ShowOnProductPage
      AND T.DisplayOrder = M.DisplayOrder
  )
```